# Insert data in database using umbraco mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I am trying to store data entered on my form, to my database table but it simply doesn't work, here is the model and a controller is someone wants to take a look,using mvc 5 and umbraco.

```
[TableName("staffOnGoingTraining")]  
[PrimaryKey("id")]  
public class CreateEmployeeViewModel    
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]  
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Training Name")]
    public string TrainingName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Expected Cost")]
    public string TrainingCost { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime TrainingStartDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Expected Completion Date")]
    [UIHint("NullableDateTime")]
    public DateTime TrainingExpires { get; set; }
}

public class CreateEmployeeViewController : SurfaceController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEmployee(CreateEmployeeViewModel viewModel)
    {

        if (Utils.staffDetail.accessLevel > accessLevel.admin)
        {
            return Content("You are not authorized to edit this information");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;
            var sql = new Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Sql();
            db.Insert(viewModel);
            return PartialView("_Create", viewModel);
        }

        return Content("Thank you, your changes have been saved");

    }
}
```

Comment: "it simply doesn't work" can you elaborate? do you have any errors? did you debug step by step the action in your controller?

Comment: `it simply doesn't work` what does this mean? Are you getting any error? What error? What's your findings after debugging?